# Плавное изменение размера объекта unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, scale

помогите сделать плавное увеличение и уменьшение размеров кнопки программно. Я написал код, но он почему-то изменяется слишком быстро.

```
if (goUp)
        {

            VideoBtn.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(VideoBtn.transform.localScale, endLocale,1f);
            if (VideoBtn.transform.localScale == endLocale)
                goUp = false;
        }
        if (!goUp)
        {
            VideoBtn.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(VideoBtn.transform.localScale, startLocale,1f);
            if (VideoBtn.transform.localScale == startLocale)
                goUp = true;

        }
```

Comment: 1f поменяй на например `Time.deltaTime * _scalingTime`, где *_scalingTime* это float поле, принимающее значения от 0 до 1. Чем меньше значение > тем медленнее выполняется `Lerp()`

Comment: Поменял значение. Теперь практически ничего не изменяется даже при Time.deltaTime без коэффициентов

Comment: у тебя в `Update()` находится приведенный код?

Comment: это как понять?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ResizeObject : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform _transform;
    private IEnumerator _resizeCoroutine;

    private void Start () {
        _transform = transform; // кешируем трансформ
        Resize(2f, 5);
    }

    public void Resize (float time, float size) {
        Resize(time, new Vector2(size, size, size));
    }

    public void Resize (float time, Vector3 size) {
        // останавливаем ресайз если он происходит
        if (_resizeCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(_resizeCoroutine);
        // запускаем корутину ресайза
        _resizeCoroutine = ResizeCoroutine(time, size);
        StartCoroutine(_resizeCoroutine);
    }

    private IEnumerator ResizeCoroutine (float time, Vector3 target) {
        float Timer = 0;
        Vector3 Base = _transform.localScale;
        while (Timer < time) {
            _transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(Base, target, Timer/time);
            yield return null; // задержка цикла до следующего кадра
            Timer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        _transform.localScale = target;
        _resizeCoroutine = null;
    }
}
```

Для не линейной интерполяции по кривой используется `AnimationCurve`

```
[SerializeField] private AnimationCurve _curve; // поле класса, настраивается в инспекторе
...
_transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(Base, target, _curve.Evaluate(Timer/time);
```

Comment: а вот еще вопрос. Почему когда делаю анимацию через окно animation она выглядит нормально, а когда в игре она очень быстро проигрывается?